# integration partial fraction typo in problem?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

so it goes from 10(x+5) to 10(x+4) at the step of integrating

[image]

i might be missing a step of how to integrate these problems properly, though im just confused how the denominator changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a typo. It should continue to be $x+5$ throughout the problem.

Comment: okay thanks !..